# Merge multiple lists of data together by common ID in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have multiple lists of data from 4 different sources with a common set of IDs that I would like to merge together, based on ID, basically ending up with a new list, one for each ID and a single entry for each source.

The objects in the output list from each of the 4 sources look something like this:

```
type data = {ID : int; value : decimal;}
```

so, for example I would have:

```
let sourceA = [data1, data2, data3];
let sourceB = [data1, data2, data3];
let sourceC = [data1, data2, data3];
let sourceD = [data1, data2, data3];
```

(I realize this code is not valid, just trying to give a basic idea... the lists are actually pulled and generated from a database)

I would then like to take sourceA, sourceB, sourceC and sourceD and process them into a list containing objects something like this:

```
type dataByID = {ID : int; valueA : decimal; valueB : decimal; valueC : decimal; valueD : decimal; }
```

...so that I can then print them out in a CSV, with the first column being the ID and coulmns 2 - 5 being data from sources A - D corresponding to the ID in that row.

I'm totally new to F#, so what would be the best way to process this data so that I match up all the source data values by ID??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you could simply concatenate all the lists and then use `Seq.groupBy` to get a list that contains unique IDs in the input lists and all values associated with the ID. This can be done using something like:

```
let data = 
  [ data1; data2; data3; data4 ]   // Create list of lists of items 
  |> Seq.concat                    // Concatenate to get a single list of items
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun d -> d.ID)   // Group elements by ID

seq { for id, values in data -> 
        // ID is the id and values is a sequence with all values 
        // (that come from any data source) }
```

If you want to associate the source (whether it was `data1`, `data2, etc...) with the value then you can first use`map` operation to add an index of the data source:

```
let addIndex i data = 
  data |> Seq.map (fun v -> i, v)

let data = 
  [ List.map (addIndex 1) data1;
    List.map (addIndex 2) data2;
    List.map (addIndex 3) data3;
    List.map (addIndex 4) data4 ]
  |> Seq.concat
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun (index, d) -> d.ID)
```

Now, `data` also contains index of the data source (from 1 to 3), so when iterating over the values, you can use index to find out from which data source the item comes from. Even nicer version can be written using `Seq.mapi` to iterate over list of data sources and add index to all the values automatically:

```
let data = 
  [ data1; data2; data3; data4 ]
  |> Seq.mapi (fun index data -> Seq.map (addIndex index) data)
  |> Seq.concat
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun (index, d) -> d.ID)
```

Comment: as I said, totally new to F#... I think I get the basic idea, but a quick code example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Adam: Added some examples :-)