# Idiomatic way to "merge" multiple lists of the same length in F#?

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, idioms

I have a number of lists - each instance of which contains 9 floating point numbers. What I effectively need to do is produce one new list that takes the first element from each of my lists and adds them together as my first element, then add the second element from each list as my second element, etc.

So effectively, if my data looks something like this:

```
List1 = [a1; b1; c1; d1; e1; f1; g1; h1; i1]
List2 = [a2; b2; c2; d2; e2; f2; g2; h2; i2]
...
Listn = [an; bn; cn; dn; en; fn; gn; hn; in]
```

Then I need to produce a new list Listx such that

```
Listx = [a1 + a2 + ... + an; b1 + b2 + ... + bn; ... ]
```

The number of lists I will be merging will vary (sometimes I may only have a single list of 9 numbers, and sometimes more than 100 lists, always 9 elements long), so I was wondering if anybody's got any advice on a nice idiomatic way of doing this?

I did have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525952/fastest-way-to-merge-lists-that-have-a-common-field) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787226/merge-multiple-lists-of-data-together-by-common-id-in-f) but both appear to advocate an intermediate step of indexing my elements first and then using groupby. This bugs me because a) I get the feeling there might be a more elegant solution for my particular case and b) performance may be an issue later - I don't want to optimize prematurely, but I also don't want to shoot myself in the foot.

Comment: "*performance may be an issue later - I don't want to optimize prematurely, but I also don't want to shoot myself in the foot.*" I agree with this sentiment, but it's worth noting that if you properly encapsulate the functionality then changing the implementation later if performance is an issue should be painless and not affect the rest of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution which works on a list of lists with the same length:

```
let mapN f = function
   | []  -> []
   | xss -> List.reduce (List.map2 f) xss

let inline merge xss = mapN (+) xss

// Usage
let yss = List.init 1000 (fun i -> [i+1..i+9])
let ys = merge yss
```

Comment: You need to mark `sumAll` `inline` for it work with `float` and other numeric types.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go via something easier like a matrix:

```
let merge xss =
  let m = matrix xss
  List.map (m.Column >> Seq.sum) [0..m.NumCols-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
let merge lists =
  let rec impl acc lists =
    match List.head lists with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | _  -> let acc' = (lists |> List.map List.head |> List.reduce (+))::acc
            let lists' = List.map List.tail lists
            impl acc' lists'
  impl [] lists
```

Some notes:

- `List.reduce (+)` is used instead of `List.sum` or `List.sumBy` because the latter only work for numeric types whereas `(+)` can work for e.g. `string`.
- `merge` is deduced to be of type `int list list -> int list` rather than being generic due to subtleties of the way operator `+` works. If you only need this to work for a single type, and that type is *not* `int` (e.g. `float`), then adding a type annotation to `merge` will be sufficient:

  ```
  let merge (lists:float list list) =
  ```
- `merge` can be marked `inline` and then will work for any type that supports operator `+`, but this will lead to lots of bloat in your IL if there are more than one or two call-sites. If you have multiple types that need to work with `merge`, and all are known beforehand, then a good workaround here is to make `merge` `inline` (and possibly `private`) then define different type-specific functions that are implemented in terms of the generic `merge`:

  ```
  let inline merge lists =
    let rec impl acc lists =
      match List.head lists with
      | [] -> List.rev acc
      | _  -> let acc' = (lists |> List.map List.head |> List.reduce (+))::acc
              let lists' = List.map List.tail lists
              impl acc' lists'
    impl [] lists

  let mergeInts (lists:int list list) = merge lists
  let mergeFloats (lists:float list list) = merge lists
  let mergeStrings (lists:string list list) = merge lists
  ```

  If you then only call the type-specific `merge`s, the IL bloat should be negligible.
- Lastly, if performance is *really* a concern, then use arrays rather than lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Shamelessly stolen from:
// http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#transpose
let rec transpose = function
  | [] -> []
  | ([] :: xss) -> transpose xss
  | ((x :: xs) :: xss) -> (x :: List.map List.head xss) :: transpose (xs :: List.map List.tail xss)

let fuse = transpose >> List.map List.sum

printfn "%A" (fuse [[3; 4]; [1; 90]; [34; 89]]) // prints [38; 183]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative one liner with default values when the list of lists is empty:

```
let sumVertically length = List.fold (List.map2 (+)) (List.replicate length 0)

//usage
//stolen from pad's answer
let listOfLists = List.init 1000 (fun i -> [i+1..i+9])
sumVertically 9 listOfLists
```